# How can I implement 2 x axis in D3 version 4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to implement two x axis (Major and minor axis) using D3.
I already have both of them been displayed, but my second axis is not displayng the domain properly.

Here's the code on codepen: http://codepen.io/wendelcosta/pen/QpzzgJ

```
g.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis axis--x2")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(x2));
```

I need to display the days for the months as minor ticks in between the major ticks (Months), it should looks like the following image.

[Click Here for Image Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxlxh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use **two** time scales for the `x` axis.

In the "day" axis, you can set the axis generator using `d3.timeDay`:

```
call(d3.axisBottom(x2)
    .ticks(d3.timeDay.every(6))
    .tickFormat(d => d3.timeFormat("%d")(d)));
```

And in the "month" axis, you increase the tick size:

```
call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickSizeInner(20)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b %y")));
```

Here is your updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqOPRg?editors=0010

I'm printing just one on every 6 days, still the "day" axis is terribly crowded. Now it's up to you reducing the text size or reducing the number of ticks.

EDIT: Since OP asked [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148538/how-can-i-implement-2-x-axis-in-d3-version-4/43152380#comment73444630_43152380) to show only values present in the data array, here is another CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrvdWq?editors=0010

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for that. I'm getting what I need to display. The only thing is that on the minor axis (x2), I need to display the actual dates from d.date and not only an interval. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: They are the actual dates.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I need to display the actual dates from the csv, and not a range like 01,08,15,22,29 for every month

Comment: from this csv: var dummy = "date,BH,BD,PB\n01 Jan 16,15843,9280,2423\n08 Jan 16,15843,9280,2423\n15 Jan 16,2869,2578,762\n22 Jan 16,1380,1450,580\n29 Jan 16,1438,1945,958\n01 Feb 16,1138,9145,358\n08 Feb 16,2138,3145,258\n15 Feb 16,7138,1145,458\n22 Feb 16,7138,6145,558\n01 Mar 16,2736,2509,3450\n08 Mar 16,1736,6509,7450\n15 Mar 16,3736,5509,2450\n22 Mar 16,4290,4894,2348\n29 Mar 16,9736,7509,2950"; I need to display the month and year on the major axis, and the days from the csv on the minor axis